# Compactness of Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Zariski-closed subgroup of $GL(V)$, where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional complex vector space.

> **Question**. Does $G$ have the structure of a compact Lie group?

Such $G$ certainly is a Lie group. Being an algebraic variety, it is compact (*quasi-compact* is the common terminology), but it is not compact in the analytic topology, as it is affine. So, maybe, my actual question is:

> **Question $\star$**. When an algebraic variety has the structure of a Lie group, is this structure understood via the Zariski topology, or
>   the analytic topology?

Thanks!

Comment: The only compact algebraic subsets of GL(V) (in the analytic topology) are finite ones. This follows from the fact that this group is affine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, e.g. $G$ could be all of $\text{GL}(V)$. (But $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, despite not being compact, turns out to be controlled in a precise sense by its [maximal compact subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) $\text{U}(n)$.)
2. The analytic topology; a variety with the Zariski topology isn't even Hausdorff, let alone a manifold.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted to know. But what do you mean by $GL(n)$ being "controlled" by $U(n)$?

Comment: @Brenin: I mean two things by this, which is why I didn't want to be precise. First, $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ deformation retracts onto $\text{U}(n)$, so the two are homotopy equivalent. But second, it turns out that the two have essentially the same representation theory, provided that you're careful to restrict your attention to algebraic representations of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.